# PySpark: Find specific value in a grouped data and mark entire group as different value

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, aws-glue, apache-spark-dataset

I have employee data like below. I want to group the below data by EMP_ID and if 'Status' of this grouped EMP_ID has the value 'Not Done' then entire 'overall_status' for the EMP_ID should be marked as 'Not Done'. How can I achieve this in Dataframe or SparkSql?

**Input:**

| EMP_ID | Status |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Done |
| 1 | Not Done |
| 1 | Done |
| 2 | Done |
| 2 | Done |

**Expected Output:**

| EMP_ID | Status | overall_status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Done | Not Done |
| 1 | Not Done | Not Done |
| 1 | Done | Not Done |
| 2 | Done | Done |
| 2 | Done | Done |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried to solve it using a simple strategy.

I have done a groupby on `EMP_ID` and collected distinct values of the `Status` columns.

Then I created a `overall_status` column based on the fact if the distinct values contain `Not Done` then that column will have value `Not Done` else `Done`.

Then joined this created dataframe with the original on `EMP_ID`

```
import sys
from pyspark import SparkContext, SQLContext
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf


sc = SparkContext('local')
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)


data1 = [

["1",   "Done"],
["1",   "Not Done"],
["1",   "Done"],
["2",   "Done"],
["2",   "Done"],
      ]

df1Columns = ["EMP_ID", "Status"]
df1 = sqlContext.createDataFrame(data=data1, schema = df1Columns)


df1.show(n=100, truncate=False)


df1_unique_values = df1.groupby("EMP_ID").agg(F.collect_set( F.col("Status")).alias("distinct_status")) \
                        .withColumn("overall_status", F.when(  F.array_contains( F.col("distinct_status"), "Not Done"), "Not Done").otherwise("Done")  ).drop("distinct_status")

df1_unique_values.show(n=100, truncate=False)


df1_final =  df1.join(df1_unique_values, on=["EMP_ID"])


df1_final.show(n=100, truncate=False)
```

Output:

```
+------+--------+
|EMP_ID|Status  |
+------+--------+
|1     |Done    |
|1     |Not Done|
|1     |Done    |
|2     |Done    |
|2     |Done    |
+------+--------+

+------+--------------+
|EMP_ID|overall_status|
+------+--------------+
|1     |Not Done      |
|2     |Done          |
+------+--------------+

+------+--------+--------------+
|EMP_ID|Status  |overall_status|
+------+--------+--------------+
|1     |Done    |Not Done      |
|1     |Not Done|Not Done      |
|1     |Done    |Not Done      |
|2     |Done    |Done          |
|2     |Done    |Done          |
+------+--------+--------------+
```